# Clarify definition of $\left\lVert f \right\rVert _{\infty}$in Rudin's "Real & Complex Analysis"

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, definition

I fear I may be overlooking something obvious.
In Rudin's "Real & Complex Analysis" chapter 3 on $L_p$-spaces, we get

> **3.7 Definition** Let $X$ be a measure space with a positive measure $\mu$.
>
> Suppose $g: X \to [0, \infty]$ is measurable. let $S$ be the set of all real $\alpha$ such that
>   $$\mu(g^{-1}((\alpha, \infty])) = 0.$$
>   If $S = \emptyset$, put $\beta = \infty$. If $S \ne \emptyset$, put $\beta = \text{inf } S$.
>   ...
>   Call $\beta$ the *essential supremum* of $g$.
>
> If $f$ is a complex measurable function on $X$, we define $\left\lVert f \right\rVert _{\infty}$to be the essential supremum of $\left\lvert f \right\rvert $, and we let $L^{\infty}(\mu)$ consist of all $f$ for which $\left\lVert f \right\rVert _{\infty} < \infty$.

**Question:** It seems to me that with this definition, the infinity norm will be $-\infty$ whenever $X$ itself has measure $0$. Other definitions that I've seen (like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-infinity) prevent this from happening. Am I failing to interpret Rudin's definition correctly?

Comment: Sorry, let me make a small edit.

Comment: Let $X$ be a measure space with a positive measure $\mu$. Rudin is saying the range of the measure $\mu$ is non-negative, not that the space itself has positive measure.

Comment: Again, Rudin's definition of "positive measure" allows it to be identically zero...

Comment: OK cool. Where should it be tightened up? Should $L^{\infty}$ allow spaces of measure 0?

Comment: He should have put $\alpha\in[0,\infty]$, after all the target of $X$ is that set, not all the reals.

Comment: Just replace "real $\alpha$" with "real $\alpha \ge 0$" in the definition.

Comment: @EricM.Schmidt That's feels good. Thanks.

Comment: Your interpretation of the highlighted section is correct. But it's probably not what he wanted to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check Rudin's definition of preimage. The preimage of a function $g : X \to Y$ is usually only defined for subsets of the codomain $Y$. Hence, since by definition it only makes sense to talk about the preimage of $\left]\alpha, \infty\right]$ under $g$ when $\left]\alpha, \infty\right] \subseteq Y$, the set $S$ of all real $\alpha$ such that $\mu(g^{-1}( \left]\alpha, \infty\right])) = 0$ only contains $\alpha \ge 0$. Thus if $\mu(X) = 0$, then $S = \left]0,\infty\right]$.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I verified that he, unlike some other authors and in some other contexts, defines the pre-image of a set only for subsets of the specified codomain. While that's not really my preference, it does resolve the issue. Thanks!